# Vim - select/yank/delete content between brackets including brackets

Tags: vim

In vim, is it possible to select content between the brackets inclusive of the brackets similar to

```
yi{ yi(
```

But I want to include the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the cursor over one bracket, and do `vf{` or `vf(` to bring you into visual mode and then select everything until (and including) the bracket.

Comment: Actually, this will end up selecting only the opening brace. If you're on top of the opening brace, `f{` will move you to the closest opening brace, which you're already on. What you probably want is `v%` which will move you to the matching brace and can be used on either side.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  See @garyjohn's answer below.

Answer (score 110):

Yes. Use `a` instead of `i`, as

```
ya{
ya(
```

See

```
:help a{
:help a(
```

and more generally,

```
:help text-objects
:help 04.8
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: very convenient! :)

Comment: Some blocks end with a comma, and this command do not copy the entire line. Do you know a way to copy it all? For example in `lua` you can have a block like `{ { name = "steam-turbine", craft-time = 3, }, { name = "boiler", craft-time =2, }, },` (since this is a comment, I cant put one in each line, but imagine the block as one command per line). Now the last line of a block is `},` and it would be useful to copy both chars.

Comment: What I would do is first select the block linewise with `Va{`, then yank the selected text with `y`. This is documented in `:help v_object-select`, but I don't think it's very clear.

Answer (score 5):

Does `f{v%` or `f(v%` do what you want? It moves your cursor to the next { or (, enters you into visual mode, and then moves your cursor to the corresponding closing } or ). If you're already past the scope you want to select, you can use a capital `F`. Works just as well to jump to the closing } or ) first, too -- `f}v%`.

Once you have what you want selected, you can `y`, `d`, `x`, etc. it. The `%` command works multi-line, too, so you can use this technique on large blocks of code if you wish (although `f` and `F` do not, so you have to start on either the first or last line).

**EDIT:** Better answer, seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

`ya(`

Replacing the `i` in your original command with `a` does exactly the same thing, except that it *includes* the '(' character. This is "yanking **a** block", whereas `yi(` is "yanking an **i**nner block".

Answer (score 5):

One another way would be by following the below steps:

1. place the cursor on the opening parenthesis `(` or braces `{`
2. press `esc` key and press `v` to enter into the visual mode
3. now press the `%` symbol (this will select the whole text between parens inclusive)
4. press the key `y` to *yank* (i.e. copy) the text (press `d` if you rather want to cut it.)

Then, you can move the cursor wherever you want the new text to be pasted and then press `p` for pasting the text there.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I use `vi{` or `va{` to select the content between brackets.
The advantage is that you will be able to see the selection before you yank it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).